# Android : repo sync : downloading >100%

Tags: android, synchronization, repository

i am downloading the android source tree following this guide

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Now after the "repo sync", its just going on and on and on

i am seeing this ::

```
Downloading device/samsung/tuna: 452% (556MB/123MB)  
Receiving objects:   7% (154/2030), 2.82 MiB | 120 KiB/s
.
.
.
Downloading device/samsung/tuna: 470% (579MB/123MB)  
Receiving objects:  80% (2783/3471), 13.56 MiB | 104 KiB/s
```

I really feel something is wrong :-/ how can it download 470%?

my connection is not very consistent, and it keeps going off at times (once in an hour), i have been doing "repo sync -f" since a lot of hours.

Comment: the whole repo is huge (several GB) - maybe it's just a display error.

Comment: @zapl do i need to download the whole repo ? any way i can just download the important parts to build the "hello world" rom first ??

Comment: you need the whole thing to build a hello world rom - http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, it is stuck on frameworks/base @ 634%.

But you can download without repo according to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704844/downloading-the-android-source-not-via-git-repo

not perfect, but ok for a hello world rom I guess.